# SCSS Passing variable to keyframe inside a mixin

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I'm trying to create an animation which involves moving several cloud at different speeds to animate a sky. In an attempt to create reusable code I have moved to mixins but I seem to have run in a problem.

The clouds have different starting positions (e.g defined by right: 100px - passed at $startpos).
On the initial pageload the clouds are at the correct position but the animation starts from a random right position.

my scss code is looking like this

```
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to   { opacity: 1 }
}

@mixin cloud($height, $width, $bg, $startpos, $slowanim, $fastanim) {
    background: url($bg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    border: none;

    height: $height; // 800
    width: $width; // 800

    position: absolute;
    right: $startpos;

    opacity: 1;
    animation: movecloudA $fastanim infinite;

    &.animate {
        animation: fadein 5s, movecloud $slowanim infinite;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    @include keyframes(movecloud) {
        0% { right: $startpos; }
        100% { right: 100%; animation: movecloud $slowanim infinite;}
    }

}

.cloudA {
    @include cloud(800px, 800px, 'assets/cloudA.svg', -100px, 5s, 1s)
    bottom: -400px;
}

.cloudB {
    @include cloud(1200px, 1200px, 'assets/cloudB.svg', -1500px, 9s, 5s)
    bottom: -800px;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

the behaviour can be reproduced on https://meshto.space/, after hovering on the exclamation mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to figure this out with some more experimenting.

It seems that keyframe animations are not wrapped up inside a scope and need to have a unique name. The behavior above was actually not random and changed the right offset to -1500 for both clouds once the animation was started.

i.e. all your animations need to have unique names.

The code above was changed to

```
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to   { opacity: 1 }
}

@mixin cloud($bg, $anim, $height, $width, $startpos, $slowanim, $fastanim) {
    background: url($bg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    border: none;

    height: $height; // 800
    width: $width; // 800

    position: absolute;
    right: $startpos;

    opacity: 1;
    // animation: movecloudA $fastanim infinite;

    &.animate {
        animation: fadein 5s, $anim $slowanim infinite;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    @include keyframes($anim) {
        0% { right: $startpos; }
        100% { right: 100% }
    }

}

.cloudA {
    @include cloud('assets/cloudA.svg', cloudAnimA, 800px, 800px, -100px, 5s, 1s)
    bottom: -400px;
}

.cloudB {
    @include cloud('assets/cloudB.svg', cloudAnimB, 1200px, 1200px, -1500px, 9s, 5s)
    bottom: -800px;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Would appreciate if there are neater solutions to this problem :). Ty